# Retrieve messages from Inbox

Tags: android, text, sms, inbox

I am making an App with the help of which I can get an ArrayList of all the Text messages. I had no problem for achieving that but when I am sending it to default SMS application of Android device, I see the text surrounding by "[]". But I don't want that brackets.

For Eg.: My Inbox has a text "Hello World", but I am getting string displaying "[Hello World]". I want the exact message that is being displayed in my Inbox. So what should i do to remove extra "[]" from my string.

Please help me on that. Thanks in advance

Comment: So your question is how to remove the brackets from that string?

Comment: Can u display any one text message body?

Comment: @Dinesh-For Ex: The original message in Inbox is "Hello World". Then I am getting "[Hello World]" in my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to send the whole `ArrayList` with `toString()` and it's displaying the brackets you can try to rebuild the string:

```
String message = "";
    for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
        message += array.get(i) + ", ";
    }
```

Where ", " can be your delimiter. But I'm not sure this is what you want, can you provide more info in the description?

**EDIT**: Try

```
String message="[Hello World]";
        message.substring(1,message.length()-1);
```

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope it help now. Kindly reply me with answer. Thanks

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid I have updated the answer. Try the code after edit.

Comment: @Alexandru-I already tried that but instead I am getting output as "[ello Worl]". So the "[]" persists !!!

Comment: No...It doesn't solve my problem. I think Brackets are added by android itself, after we store the message into list...!!!

Comment: Can you obtain the final string before you send it? If you have a plain string object that has brackets there is no problem removing them. I'm not sure what you are doing there. Post some code.

Comment: Yup. I obtained the final string and then trimmed it from both sides. Thanks 4 support. That really helped !!